# iscsid: iscsi client local port

Tags: firewall, iscsi

On remote server, the `iscsi` service listens on port `3260`.

What determines the local port used on the iscsi client ?

I am using the `open-iscsi` package, and the `/usr/sbin/iscsid` as client.

In the example below, can see with `netstat -ptn`, that my client (`1.2.3.4`) listens on port 38770:

```
tcp 0 0 1.2.3.4:38770  1.2.3.5:3260  ESTABLISHED 29161/iscsid
```

Is this port completely random, or can it be specified somewhere on the client side ?

I need to know this port in advance, so that I can configure the firewall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this port completely random, or can it be specified somewhere on the client side ?

All TCP/UDP connections work by picking a random port for the client (while the server has a well-known port). You don't get to specify the port, the OS picks it for you (though possibly the client can work around that, if you add enough code to it).

> I need to know this port in advance, so that I can configure the firewall.

No, you don't. You tell the firewall the server port, and then you tell the connection tracker of your firewall that established connections to that port should be passed through. This will deal with the random port on the client side.